# Unexcepted return value when using ifPresentOrElse lamba function

Tags: java, lambda

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error on the 
IDE `Unexpected return value` when I need to return something from a method when using lambda.

```
public Employee getEmployee(long id) {
repository.findById(id).ifPresentOrElse(
                empDetails -> {
                    return service.buildEmployee(empDetails);
                },
        () -> { throw new ResourceNotFoundException(); }
        );

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what error exactly?

Comment: @Stultuske the 'Unexpected return value'. I'm not sure what's the cause..

Comment: Would you realize what problem with this code without any error messages or stack trace?

Comment: Could you please add the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @M.Ismail hi thanks! I've updated my question to be more clear. It's an error on the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifPresentOrElse​` is used to consume the `Optional`'s value if present, and to perform some other logic otherwise. It cannot be used to return a value or throw an exception.

Instead you can combine `map` with `orElseThrow`:

```
public Employee getEmployee(long id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
                     .map(service::buildEmployee)
                     .orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll accept your answer in 3mins. :)